# Lag when resizing forms? - C#

Tags: c#, forms, resize

Hey, I notice that when I resize any forms in my programs they always lag like hell, does anyone know how to prevent this without just making it wait until I finish resizing before it moves everything?

Comment: Any code or something because right now all we can suggest you is to purchase a faster computer because we don't actually know what program you might have written and what code you use, ...

Comment: I'm just using the Anchor feature in Visual C# 2008 - e.g.

`this.asset_tree.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));`

Comment: It's not the Anchor, it is likely the refreshing of your Form's child controls that is causing the lag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use

```
this.SuspendLayout();
```

and

```
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Comment: Where would this go? When we resize the form, or for each of the controls on the form?